# pandas constains with regular expression- special character and full word

Tags: pandas, regex

I am trying to remove rows that contains any of this characters(@#%+*=) and also a full word

| col |
| --- |
| ahoi* |
| word |
| be |

```py
df = df[~df[col].str.contains(r'[@#%+*=](word))', regex=True)]
```

I achieved to remove special characters only with .str.contains(r'[@#%+*=])', however I cannot remove the row with the full word.

What am I missing?

This is the expected result.

| col |
| --- |
| be |

Comment: Do you have a problem with using a variable in the regex?

Comment: do you mean specific `word` or any word?

Comment: `word`. It is just a specif word that I want to identify in order to remove rows.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you need to use the or operator (`|`) instead of *parenthesis* :

```
df = df[~df["col"].str.contains(r'[@#%+*=]|word', regex=True)]
```

​
Output :

```
print(df)
  col
2  be
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
>>> df[~df['col'].str.contains(r'(?:[@#%+*=]|word)', regex=True)]
  col
2  be
```